# How to improve this find() function (or similar)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'd like inquire about how to improve this working code to skip execution of [i] if one of the four stop words is found in [table_t1.keys].

```
for i in table_t1.keys():
    if i.find("data") == -1:
        if i.find("split") == -1:
            if i.find("loss") == -1:
                if i.find("prob") == -1:
                    #do something
```

Using the find-function is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the words, like this

```
words = ("data", "split", "loss", "prob")
```

Now, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) functions, like this

```
if all(word not in i for word in words):
    ...

if not any(word in i for word in words):
    ...
```

They both basically check if none of the words from `words` tuple exist in `i`.

---

NOTE: If `table_t1` is actually a dictionary, then you don't have to call `.keys` (it will create a list of keys). You can simply iterate it like this

```
for i in table_t1:
```